# How to read csv file to get output without list but in normal String?

Tags: python, list, csv, csvreader

I would like to ask how to change code to get output:

```
Nigel;UK;19
John;US;22
Carol;Germany;26
```

no this input (is it list?):

```
['Nigel', 'UK', '19']
['John', 'US', '22']
['Carol', 'Germany', '26']
```

code:

```
import csv

with open('friends.csv', 'r') as source:
    reader = csv.reader(source)

    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

I think that now exist some instructions for it but I did not find it.
Thank you

Comment: try use with open('friends.csv', 'r') as source: reader = source.readlines() for line in reader: print(line)

Comment: Thank you, but it would be better without free lines between every line.

Comment: And also need ; between words insted of ,

Comment: `print(';'.join(line))`

Comment: so you can use `print(line.replace('\n', ''))`

Comment: Does the first block show your input file or does it show your expected output? What is the separator in your input file? Commas or semicolons?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi In my code it was at first mentioned output like `['Nigel', 'UK', '19']` but with your both answers I have right output, thank´s.

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear and could be improved. For future reference, there's two ways to interpret the question: do you want the output printed to appear as a string, or do you want each line within an *actual* string variable? The interpretation is made ambiguous because you're not actually assigning each line to anything, you're just printing the result out in above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the output as a list because *that's what `csv.reader()` does!* It reads each line of a csv file, converts it to a list taking into account commas and escaping rules, and returns that list.

If you don't care about each individual element of the csv file, just read the file as a regular file:

```
with open("filename.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end="")
```

the `end=""` argument prevents `print()` from adding its own newline characters, since the `line` from the file already includes the newline character

Alternatively, you can still read it as a csv file, but `str.join()` the resulting list before printing it. Use this if you are using the rows of the csv file as a list somewhere else, but you just want to print the file here

```
with open('friends.csv', 'r') as source:
    reader = csv.reader(source)
    for line in reader:
        print(";".join(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try unpacking the list elements via the `*` operator, and pass a custom separator to `print`:

```py
import csv

with open('friends.csv', 'r') as source:
    reader = csv.reader(source)

    for line in reader:
        print(*line, sep=';')
```

Result:

```
Nigel;UK;19
John;US;22
Carol;Germany;26
```

An easier (and more efficient) approach would be to read in file contents as a string, and then replace all commas with a colon:

```py
with open('friends.csv', 'r') as source:
    print(source.read().replace(',', ';'))
```

Note, this assumes the contents of your `friends.csv` is as follows:

```py
Nigel,UK,19
John,US,22
Carol,Germany,26
```